# Spivak wrote "in some open set $U$ containing $A$". Why? (Calculus on Manifolds, partition of unity)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

Spivak wrote "Since $\{D_1, \dots, D_n\}$ covers $A$, we have $\psi_1(x) + \dots + \psi_n(x) > 0$ for all $x$ ***in some open set $U$ containing $A$***".

Spivak didn't write "Since $\{\text{int } D_1, \dots, \text{int } D_n\}$ covers $A$, we have $\psi_1(x) + \dots + \psi_n(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $\text{int } D_1 \cup \dots \cup \text{int } D_n$ which is open and contains $A$".

Why?

And I think it is possible to take $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the domain of $\phi$'s.

But Spivak didn't take $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the domain of $\phi$'s.

Why?

Spivak was certainly right, but why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Spivak isn't/wasn't certainly right. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361740) for instance.

Comment: The set $\{x\,\psi_1(x)+\ldots+\psi_n(x) > 0\}$ contains each $D_i$ and is open because the sum of the $\psi_k$ is a continuous function.