# What are all angle preserving linear operators on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, linear-transformations

I´m working on Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and I met this exercise. My immediate answer was 'all the rotations' but I can't explain why. Am I right? Can you give a hint or something to be able to answer this question in a more formal way?

Comment: What about reflections and multiples of rotations?

Comment: That ones too. But is there a way to prove that all are of that kind?

Comment: Hint: preserve angles means preserve: $\langle v,w \rangle/|v||w|$

Comment: The angle between two non-zero vectors can be expressed in terms of the dot product. A good starting place is to investigate $T$ such that for some real number $\lambda$, you have $\langle Tx, Ty\rangle = \lambda\langle x, y\rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can see that rotations preserve angles, but then so do reflections and uniform expansions. Note that the rotation transformation $T(x,y)=(x \cos \theta, y \sin \theta)$ is an [orthogonal transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation) and that the expansion and reflection transformations essentially boil down to $T(v_1,v_2)=(\lambda_1 v_1, \lambda_2 v_2)$, where $\{ v_1, v_2 \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|$. Hence we can conjecture that a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is angle-preserving precisely when $kT:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is orthogonal, for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not playing any special role in this conjecture any more, so we can go ahead and attempt a proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

#### Proof:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $kT$ is orthogonal. Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then,
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\big\langle T(x), T(y) \big\rangle}{\|T(x)\| \, \|T(y)\|}\right)
= \arccos\left(\frac{\big\langle kT(x), kT(y) \big\rangle}{\|kT(x)\| \, \|kT(y)\|}\right)
= \arccos\left(\frac{\big\langle x, y \big\rangle}{\|x\| \, \|y\|}\right)
$$
because $\|kT(x)\|^2=\big\langle kT(x), kT(x) \big\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle = \|x\|^2$, so $\|kT(x)\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$. Hence, $T$ is angle-preserving.

Conversely, suppose that $T$ is angle-preserving. Let $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then,
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\big\langle T(e_i), T(e_j) \big\rangle}{\|T(e_i)\| \, \|T(e_j)\|} \right)
=\arccos\left(\frac{\big\langle e_i, e_j \big\rangle}{\|e_i\| \, \|e_j\|} \right)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \big\langle T(e_i), T(e_j) \big\rangle = \|T(e_i)\| \, \|T(e_j)\| \, \big\langle e_i, e_j \big\rangle = \|T(e_i)\| \, \|T(e_j)\| \, \delta_{ij}
$$

Now, let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\big\langle T(x), T(y) \big\rangle &= \Big\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i T(e_i), \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j T(e_j) \Big\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_i y_j \big\langle T(e_i), T(e_j) \big\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_i y_j \|T(e_i)\| \, \|T(e_j)\| \, \delta_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i \| T(e_i) \|^2
\end{align}
$$

Now, taking a hint from [rschwieb's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355893/279515) to a similar question: [Action of angle-preserving linear transformation on basis vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354848/279515), we can conclude that $\|T(e_i)\|=\|T(e_j)\|=\lambda$ (say). If $k=1/\lambda$, then $\big\langle kT(x), kT(y) \big\rangle = \big\langle x, y \big\rangle.$

Hence, proved.

Answer (score 0):

*I am slightly unsatisfied with my [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526159/279515) solution to this problem, so I give below another answer that is laid out in the same spirit as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177042/279515) by [@JasonDeVito](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/331/jason-devito) to Problem 1-8(b)<sup>[1]</sup>.*

---

By Problem 1-8(a)<sup>[1]</sup>, we know that if $T \colon \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$
is norm preserving then it is angle preserving. Clearly, if $T$ is angle
preserving, then so is $cT$ for any nonzero scalar $c$. We shall show that,
conversely, for any angle preserving $T \colon \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$
there exists a nonzero scalar $c$ such that $cT$ is norm preserving. This will
characterise angle preserving linear operators on $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Suppose that there exist unit vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$
with $\lVert T(\mathbf{x}) \rVert \neq \lVert T(\mathbf{y}) \rVert$.
Then, on the one hand, we have
    $$
  \langle \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \rangle
   = \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \rangle - \langle \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{y} \rangle
   = 1 - 1
   = 0,
 $$
so $\angle(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y},\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) = \pi/2$.
But, on the other hand, we have
    \begin{align*}
  \langle T(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}), T(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) \rangle
   &= \langle T(\mathbf{x}), T(\mathbf{x}) \rangle - \langle T(\mathbf{y}), T(\mathbf{y})\rangle \\
   &= \lVert T(\mathbf{x}) \rVert^2 - \lVert T(\mathbf{y}) \rVert^2\\
   &\neq 0.
 \end{align*}
Also note that $T(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y})$ and $T(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})$
are nonzero vectors. Hence, we can talk about
    $$
  \frac{\langle T(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}), T(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) \rangle}{\lVert T(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) \rVert \cdot \lVert T(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})\rVert}.
 $$
Since this is nonzero, it implies that
$\angle(T(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}),T(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})) \neq \pi/2$.
Thus, $T$ is not angle preserving. Hence, if $T$ is angle preserving,
then $\lVert T(\mathbf{x}) \rVert$ equals a constant, say $r$, for
all unit vectors $\mathbf{x}$. But then, if $\mathbf{x}$ is any
nonzero vector, then
$r = \lVert T(\mathbf{x}/\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert) \rVert = \lVert T(\mathbf{x}) \rVert/\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert$.
Hence, for $c := r^{-1}$, $cT$ is norm preserving.

Thus, the angle preserving linear transformations
$T \colon \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$
are precisely those for which there exists a scalar $c$ such that
$cT \colon \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ is norm preserving.

---

**Notes:**

1. Here is the complete statement of the problem for ease of reference (*Calculus on Manifolds*, Michael Spivak, pages 4–5):

> **1-8.** $\quad$ If $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are non-zero, the **angle** between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$,
>   denoted $\angle(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, is defined as
>   $\arccos\left(\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \rangle / \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \cdot \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert \right)$,
>   which makes sense by Theorem 1-1(2)<sup>[2]</sup>.
>   The linear transformation $T$ is
>   **angle preserving** if $T$ is $1$-$1$, and for $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \neq \mathbf{0}$ we have $\angle(T(\mathbf{x}),T(\mathbf{y})) = \angle(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$.
>
> $\quad$  (a) Prove that if $T$ is norm preserving, then $T$ is angle preserving.
>
> $\quad$  (b) Suppose there is a basis $\mathbf{x}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{x}_n$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$ and numbers $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ such that $T(\mathbf{x}_i) = \lambda_i \mathbf{x}_i$. Prove that if $T$ is angle preserving, then all $\lvert \lambda_i \rvert$ are equal.
>
> $\quad$  (c) What are all angle preserving $T\colon\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$?

2. Theorem 1-1(2) (on page 2) says that if $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbf{R}^n$, then $\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n x^i y^i \rvert = \lvert \mathbf{x} \rvert \cdot \lvert \mathbf{y} \rvert$.