# Suppose $\Vert Ax\Vert _{2}=\Vert Bx\Vert _{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ , does that imply $A=B$ or $A=-B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are matrices such that $\Vert Ax\Vert _{2}=\Vert Bx\Vert _{2}$   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ , does that imply $A=B$ or $A=-B$. I couldn't come up with a counter-example. 
If the general statement is not true, does it change anything if $A,B$ are also symmetric?

Thanks!

Comment: A matrix that satisfies $\|x\|=\|Ax\|$ is called an isometry. For instance any change of basis matrix or unitary matrix is an isometry. Also $\|Ux\|=\|UAx\|$ for all matrices A and isometries U.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ must have identical kernels. So, if you consider the restrictions of them on the subspace orthogonal to their common kernel, you may assume that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible. But then this means $\|AB^{-1}x\|_2=\|x\|_2$. It is [well-known](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177005/question-about-angle-preserving-operators) that the matrix of a norm-preserving linear map on $\mathbb R^n$ must be orthogonal. Consequently (and for the original $A$ and $B$), $\|Ax\|_2=\|Bx\|_2$ for all $x$ iff $A=QB$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Comment: What about the case where $A$ and $B$ are symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let A be a rotation matrix of 45 degrees.  Let B be a rotation matrix of 90 degrees.  Then....

Comment: Indeed any two isometries.

Comment: Just as you were responding I thought about orthonogonal matrices.. How silly of me...

Answer (score 1):

They must have same kernels. On the remaining subspace (which is just another $R^d$ space) ${B}^{-1}$ exist, thus, as  user1551 mentioned,  $\|AB^{-1}x\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x$.

We know all length preserving matrices:
[ALL Orthogonality preserving linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769021/all-orthogonality-preserving-linear-maps-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rn)

[image]

So, $A$ and $B$ hold the above, iff $A{B}^{-1}=Q$ where $Q$ is a length preserving matrix.